# Будет ли срабатывать ContentObserver в Service?

Tags: android, service

У меня есть Service, который постоянно работает в бэкграунде и никогда не умирает. Одно из его назначений, это проверять состояние телефонной книжки контактов, т.е. её БД: если контакт из неё был удалён, изменён или добавлен новый, то сервис должен отреагировать на это. Вопрос состоит в том, как сервис будет узнавать об этом. Самое "Тупое" решение, это сделать периодическую проверку БД контактов, но такой вариант убог... Один человек подсказал мне, что можно использовать ContentObserver, но его необходимо убивать вместе с смертью приложения. Если кто знает, прошу подсказать, можно ли зарегистрировать ContentObserver в Service и не убивать его, чтобы он реагировал на изменения в БД контактов. Если можно, то будет ли он реагировать даже при заблокированном телефоне (Процессор в спящем режиме), или будет необходимо использовать PowerManager для пробуждения процессора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Будет реагировать, если сделать правильный bind сервиса и приложения (bind это процесс получения приложением указателя на `Service`). После bind надо будет прокинуть в БД контактов указатель на `ContentObserver`, который будет создан внутри сервиса.

> Clients can also use Context.bindService() to obtain a persistent connection to a service.

1. Но к сожалению сервис не будет тоже жить вечно, придет время и ось его сама прибьет. Почитайте про lifecycle сервиса.

> Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this happens, the system will later try to restart the service.

Comment: Дело в том,что не прибьёт, если сделать его foregraund, это позволяет жить сервису всегда без исключений, что система не будет его грохать, даже если не будет хватать памяти. Проверено

Comment: Вопрос. А зачем получать приложением указатель на сервис? Нельзя ли ограничиться самим сервисом, или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Не путайте класс Service с его экземплаторм. Можно, конечно сделать статическую ссылку на объект `Service/ContentObserver` (паттерн Singleton), но это не совсем айс. Может получиться ситуация, что `Service` еще не стартовал, а уже есть ссылка на него.